# Query column value of related object and store as variable

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to grab the value of my column `name` in my model `Category` which is linked to my `Post` model. I want to save the value of `name` into a variable for later use. I tried `print(post.categories.name)` but it returns value `None`. I can confirm that there is an actual value by running `post.categories.values()` which returns `<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'General'}]>`

Model:

```
from django.db import models



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views:

```
def blog_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.select_related().get(pk=pk)
    category = post.categories.name # This returns None but should return General
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "comments": comments,
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "blog_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: A post can have multiple categories, which one do you want?

Comment: If you want all the names of the categories, you can do `names = [category.name for category in post.categories.all()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You defined `categories` as a `ManyToManyField` on your `Post` model, so `post.categories` is a `ModelManager` to fetch the categories and `post.categories.all()` returns *all the categories* associated to `post`.

You can get a list of names for the categories of a post like this:

```
category_names = [category.name for category in post.categories.all()]
```

Comment: Dang. Can I change this in my model so a post only can have one category? I don't plan on adding multiple categories for each post. 

The thing is that I'd like to get the pure value out of my database to save it as a variable. This returns the value as a list object ['General'] which I don't want.

Comment: If a post can only have one category then you should use a ForeignKey not a ManyToManyField